# if condition in a for-each-group BI Publisher report

Tags: xml, rtf, bi-publisher

Im trying to get a summary output that displays data based on Product that have different CwaOrderType.

```
<?for-each-group:OrderEntry-LineItems[../../CwaChannel='Customer Portal' and ../../Status='Submitted'];Product?>
<?Product?>
<?if:CwaOrderType='PRS Sales'?>
   <?count(current-group()/.)?> 
   <?sum(current-group()/CwaLineTotalAmount2)?>
<?end if?>
<?if:CwaOrderType='PRS Switching'?>
   <?count(current-group()/.)?> 
   <?sum(current-group()/CwaSwitchOutUnits)?>
<?end if?>
<?end for-each-group?>
```

However, it will return the output to blank. If I removed the if-condition, it works but it is inaccurate. Can any of you guys tell me what is missing?

Comment: Could you post the source xml ? Also if you could post what answer you are expecting , that can help.

Comment: Is it possible if I email you the xml as well as the rtf template that I have come up so far? @RanjithR

Comment: Yep, you can send those to  alt.n4-8oko8ew8@yopmail.com

Comment: @Yan You could get more help from here if post the full information here instead of sending it to individuals by email.